# PHP - Displaying Urdu text retrieved from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, functional-programming

There are book titles in Urdu language stored in MySQL database. I've to display on html page using PHP.

Currently only questions marks(`??????`) are displayed in place of Urdu text.

```
<div class='product_title'><a href='details.php?pid=".$Row['s_id']."'>".$Row["books"]."</a></div>
```

What needs to be done to display these characters properly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222386/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-unicode

Answer (score 21):

Step : 1 - Go to table structure and change collation **latin1_swedish_ci** to **utf8_general_ci**

Step : 2 -
You have to include this following tag in data results pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Step :3 - Insert 'N' Prefix. Here the N stands for National language character set. Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, [more](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)

Step :4 - PHP code displaying records form database. Before that you have to specify mysql_query() function data character set type

```
<?php
include('db.php');
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row['id']; // Book id 
echo $row['books_title']; // Book title
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also your files encoding mustbe utf-8 without BOM

Comment: This should be in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved by manipulating the character encoding of the entire PHP-MySQL environment.

By Default the character set encoding in PHPMyAdmin is generally Latin Swedish or utf8 general, However, other languages like Urdu, Chinese and more are not supported in the character set encoding, So you need to change the character encoding of your MySQL database or table or column as per your requirement.

```
# For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
# For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
# For each column:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
# (Don’t blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on the column type, maximum length, and other properties. The above line is just an example for a `VARCHAR` column.)
```

You also need to set the character encoding for the data retrieved using mysqli_query. You can do so by using mysqli_charset() function just below the connection line. Like...

```
 // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* change character set to utf8mb4 */
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");
```

Now You can display Urdu or any other Language directly by retrieving from MySQL database through PHP Query.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem and i have solved this error by convert them to UTF-8.

```
ALTER TABLE test_Table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE test_Table_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE test_Table_name CHANGE title title VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```