# the variable $name is not showing text in urdu format where as in mysql it is stored in urdu

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");   
$sql = "SELECT id, name, class FROM table_a";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "id: " . $row["id"].
           " - Name: " . $row["name"].
           "class" .$row["class"].
           "<br>";
    }
} else {
         echo "0 results";
}
```

The variable $name is not showing text in Urdu where as in mysql it is stored in Urdu.

Comment: Mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Displaying Urdu text retrieved from MySQL DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280421/php-displaying-urdu-text-retrieved-from-mysql-db)

Comment: i am beginner, do you tell me what would be difference MySQL and MySQLi are making here...

Comment: `MySQL` is the deprecated API and `MySQLi` is the current API that's been used above `5.5.0` PHP version [Deprecated features in PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and [Migrating from PHP 5.4.x to PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php) @Rizwan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
$sql = "SELECT id, name, class FROM table_a";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "id: " . $row["id"].
enter code here
 " - Name: " . $row["name"].
       "class" .$row["class"].
       "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

try this

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks dear. Now my problem is solved good suggestion, thanks again. mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8"); and mysqli both were help for solving my problem.